Is possible to prevent a pod being stopped/deleted while it's app is doing a certain task?
I'm working on an Spring application with a scheduled job which is called some times during the day, and has a variable duration. This job is also locked for one pod only - using shedlock.
The problem is that we have to care for our deploys to be done only after the job is finished, otherwise it's going to be interrupted and have to be called again from the start.
Would be possible to have any kind of Kubernetes configuration to keep that pod "indestructible" for the duration of that job?
Something like sending a sign when starting the job, and other when finishing?

Plain and simple: No. Your process will receive a SIGTERM, then a SIGKILL after a while and then the container is simply killed.
However, what you could do is to use a message queue which requires explicit acknowledgment of the messages triggering your tasks and acknowledge the respective message when a task is finished.

Of course you can in your situation, though it might be a little hacky/creative.
So you have a new version and want to prevent the Deployment to proceed to remove the old instance until it is a good time.
You can use the minReadySeconds on the Deployment and a readinessProbe or even better have an explicit startupProbe with an endpoint that checks if a shedlock is currently held. If that is true, let the startupProbe fail.
Kubernetes will not progress with the Deployment until the situation is resolved.

That still would not prevent OOM-killing.

I did not read that requirement into the question. Of course this can not be prevented, but you can influence it using PodPriority

The thing is, that this „unstoppable“ requirement is there for a reason, namely to ensure that a task is finished. Not that your answer is wrong, but the guarantee it provides is rather weak.

I think this is clear, as it does not guarantee that no node explodes, neither. But thanks for pointing it out.
